# Needed the time complexity of below code?

Tags: java, time-complexity

Will the time complexity of this code be **O(n*m)** where n is the size of ar[] and m is the maximum length of String in the ar[] or am I wrong somewhere? please can someone clarify this doubt?

```
function1(String[] ar){
     for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
       function2(ar[i]);
     }
}

function2(String str){
    for(int j=0;j<str.length();j++){
     // some operation o(1)
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, an upper bound on the worst case behavior of this function is O(n*m) as you describe. Simple choose all strings in arr to have the same length and you can see the number of iterations of the loop body in function2 is n*m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. There is no way to determine the array size by string size or vice-versa unless you have some extra information, which means that you need both m and n, or, more precisely, their product to have the result.

The actual time needed for the algorithm to be executed in practice can be expected to be around avg(m) * n, but of course, it is affected by other variables as well, like server load during the execution of the algorithm, the nature of the O(1) operation and so on.